# WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.2 and am trying to get Python's IDLE to work properly with Tcl/Tk. This is the error message I'm getting when I open IDLE:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016, 07:03:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.
```

Visiting the link in the error message, I read the documentation and installed Tcl/Tk version 8.5.18.0 from [this](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) source. Perhaps it is important to note that I'm running a `brew` install of Python 2.7.13. After I installed the DMG for 8.5.18.0, the bash terminal and Python are not recognizing the Tcl/Tk upgrade (Note that it is recognizing Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) instead of 8.5.18.0. How can I get IDLE and the upgraded python install from homebrew to recognize the upgraded Tcl/Tk 8.5.18.0? In other words, how can I resolve the warning message?

Comment: Apologies if I've misunderstood your question, but besides the fact you get the _WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable_ message, did you actually have any issues with using Python's IDLE to work properly with Tcl/Tk 8.5.9?

Comment: It is buggy--I've had several unexpected crashes.

Comment: Thanks. I see you're running Python 2.7.13. Is there a reason you're running that version instead of, say, Python 3.6.0 ?

Comment: It's the latest version of Python 2.7 installed with `brew`, which I prefer over Python 3. It is also the recommended Python release to play nice with the ActiveTcl 8.5.18.0 release, according to https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41774919/1446289) from Stack Overflow resolved the issue:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew install tcl-tk
brew install python --with-tcl-tk
```

Comment: This is no more possible as the option `--with-tcl-tk` disappeared.

Comment: the command `brew tap homebrew/dupes` is also deprecated

Answer (score 6):

According to this [Python Software Foundation](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-18-0) page:

> The Python for Mac OS X installers downloaded from this website dynamically link at runtime to Tcl/Tk macOS frameworks. The Tcl/Tk major version is determined when the installer is created and cannot be overridden. The Python 64-bit/32-bit Mac OS X installers for Python 3.6.x, 3.5.x, and 2.7.x dynamically link to Tcl/Tk 8.5 frameworks. 32-bit-only Python installers for Mac OS X dynamically link to Tcl/Tk 8.4 frameworks.
>
> In either case, the dynamically linking occurs when tkinter (Python 3) or Tkinter (Python 2) is first imported (specifically, the internal _tkinter C extension module). By default, the macOS dynamic linker looks first in /Library/Frameworks for Tcl and Tk frameworks with the proper major version. This is the standard location for third-party or built from source frameworks, including the ActiveTcl releases. If frameworks of the proper major version are not found there, the dynamic linker looks for the same version in /System/Library/Frameworks, the location for Apple-supplied frameworks shipped with macOS. (Note, you should normally not modify or delete files in /System/Library.)

**Source:** Look for the *How Python Chooses Which Tk Library To Use* subheading on https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#activetcl-8-5-18-0

Because of this, I am 99.9% certain that now you have updated to Tcl/Tk 8.5.18.0, what you need to do is to re-install Python 2.7.13.

The reason I believe this will resolve your issue is that upon reading the info I quoted, it's clear the Tcl/Tk version used by Python is chosen during the installation process and cannot be changed without installing Python again.

Answer (score 5):

### 2018 Update

System provided python/tcl-tk will always show that error.

You COULD download an [updated tcl-tk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) and an [updated python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) install (need to reinstall python to bind to new tcl-tk - install tcl/tk first!).

My PREFERRED method is using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

**uninstall development version of tcl-tk**

```
brew uninstall tcl-tk --devel
```

**install tcl-tk**

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

**uninstall python and python3** (tcl-tk binding happens when python is installed, so we need to re-install once we have tcl-tk installed)

```
brew uninstall python
brew uninstall python3
```

**reinstall python and python 3**

```
brew install python
brew install python3
```

**test**

```
brew test python
brew test python3
```

**test IDLE** ("idle" points to system installed python/tcl-tk, we'll no longer use that but might as well leave it there to prevent any future issues)

```
idle2
idle3
```

Comment: Yup. It works (Catalina 10.15.4)