# Using tkinter with Catalina, how to avoid deprecation warning?

Tags: catalina, python

I want to use the tkinter GUI library with python3 and Catalina 10.15.1, but I get a deprecation warning.

```
% python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Oct 26 2019, 09:13:24)
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.Tk()
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
```

I looked at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268880/warning-the-version-of-tcl-tk-8-5-9-in-use-may-be-unstable) but `brew install tcl-tk` and `brew install python3` but didn't help.

Is there a straightforward way to get tkinter to work, or is a different GUI library the recommended way to go? (I'm a bit worried that if I start installing new Python versions, I'll end up breaking other things.)

Comment: this should be safe to try - the breakage going newer than 3.7.4 should be very manageable and you could pin the brew python3 to 3.7.4 if breakage couldn’t be tested or contained. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/315121/5472

Comment: @bmike: I tried that uninstall/reinstall sequence and it didn't help.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752385/tkinter-test-buttons-are-invisible-when-using-pipenv seems you need to upgrade to python 3.8

Comment: I would suggest using virtenv for your Python apps and use pip to install your needed modules within each virtenv as needed. Also, what Yoan said (or 3.9 even).

Answer (score 3):

You may need to run `brew install python-tk@3.9`, which has the description ["Python interface to Tcl/Tk"](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python-tk@3.9).

If you don't want to update Tkinter, it depends on which shell you're using. First, run `echo ${SHELL}`.

If the response from that command is `/bin/zsh` or anything else ending is `zsh`, run the following:

`echo 'export TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1' >> ~/.zshrc`

There should be no output from that command, but you'll need to restart your terminal window.

If the response from the first command is something ending in `bash`, you need to run

`echo 'export TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Which also doesn't have an output, and also requires restarting the terminal window.

Sidenote: if you're running this in a Python script or something that needs to work on other computers, You'll need to add the following to it:

```py
import os
# Set environment variable
os.environ['TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION'] = 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `pip install tk` doesn't actually accomplish anything; it's actually some completely unrelated package https://pypi.org/project/tk/. There're some random websites which suggest this, but in truth it has no effect on tkinter at all.

Comment: @orthocresol you're right, I should have checked the pip docs before I posted this (tk refers to tensorkit in this case, for some reason). I'll update my answer to reflect this.